# How to find the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{\sinh(\ln(\cosh x))}{\sinh x}$

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-functions

How to find the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{\sinh(\ln(\cosh x))}{\sinh x}$?

I' ve tried the following:

$y=\frac{\sinh(\ln(\cosh x))}{\sinh x}$ . Now I should express $x$ in terms of $y$.

Then:
$$\sinh^-1 (\sinh x) =x=\sinh ^-1( \frac{\sinh(\ln(\cosh x))}{y})$$
Now I am stuck. How shall I continue and how do I get to the solution?

Comment: have you proved that an inverse exists?

Comment: You could take $$\mathrm{sinh}\ln(u) =\frac{u -1/u}{2}$$ and carry through making substitutions (but the answer below is far more beautiful).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $e^t = \cosh (x) $ then 
$$y = \dfrac{\sinh(t)}{\sinh(x)} = \dfrac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2 \sinh(x)} = \dfrac{\cosh^2 (x) - 1}{2 \sinh(x) \cosh(x)} = \dfrac{\tanh(x)}{2}$$

Comment: Quite beautiful! +1

Answer (score 3):

HINT

I would say

$f(x)=\frac{\sinh(\ln(\cosh x))}{\sinh x}=\frac{\cosh x-\frac{1}{\cosh x})}{2\sinh x}=\frac{\cosh^2x-1}{2\cosh x\sinh x}=\frac{\sinh^2x}{2\cosh x\sinh x}=\frac{1}{2}\tanh x$

Now calculate the inverse function.

Comment: great,in case you are wondering he used the identity $\sinh u=\dfrac{e^u-e^{-u}}{2}$ where $u=\ln (\cosh x)$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=y=\dfrac{\sinh (\ln \cosh x)}{\sinh x}$

we want to solve  for $x$

$\sinh x=\dfrac{\sinh (\ln \cosh x)}{y}$

$\implies x=\sinh ^{-1}\dfrac{\sinh (\ln \cosh x)}{y}=\sinh^{-1}\dfrac{y\sinh x}{y}=\sinh^{-1}(\sinh x)=x$

no inverse?

Comment: yes,unless we rewrite it differently as shown by the two users answers. since $x$ could not be expressed ito $y$